# iOS - Swift - AVPlayer: Error playing with url containing khmer unicode

Tags: ios, swift

I've just built a custom video player with AVPlayer, and I've found that I can only play video with url containing english character(for example: http://app.ournsarath.com/uploads/videos/mp4s/09_03_2018_business.mp4). Whenever I pass the url containing khmer unicode(for example: [http://app.ournsarath.com/uploads/sound/mp3s/01.06.2018Helpingothersចង់ជួយគ](http://app.ournsarath.com/uploads/sound/mp3s/01.06.2018Helpingothers%E1%9E%85%E1%9E%84%E1%9F%8B%E1%9E%87%E1%9E%BD%E1%9E%99%E1%9E%82)េ.mp4), the player doesn't play at all. 
I'm new to iOS development. Any advice or direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution by encoding the url string before passing it into AVPlayer.

```
    func setupPlayer(link: String){
    let encodedString = link.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
    if let url = URL(string: encodedString!) {
        player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        playerLayer.frame = self.frame
        player?.play()
    }
```